# What is the walking area beside a highway called in English?

Tags: nouns, terminology, image-identification

Please refer to the red arrows in the image on the left. This road is an expressway/highway, but somehow people can come up (using a staircase) and walk in this area, although I've almost never seen anyone doing that (I was here to shoot this photo).

Is there any particular name for the area like this (walking area beside a highway)?

[image: megapolis city with highway in the foreground]
[image: A highway/main road with concrete barrier separating it from the pedestrian lane]

Comment: The image is not the best, I can't see anything because it's too dark, it almost looks like a drop. Can you find a better shot, in daylight, please?

Comment: @mari-lou-a, thanks for your response, I've found the below image from the same area on Google, https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQq3cNgu7rzIZJ0_jknlP_4W-Tgt0horBc5Brru5TmOELG2HKqUEg

Comment: Pedestrian lane.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The few places I've seen this without it also being a cycle path would probably be called a *footpath* (the same word being used for a muddy path though a field and many other paths). This is in the UK, where the term *footway* is also sometimes used in official material. If cyclists also have access then *cycle path/track* is in common use though *shared use path* is more correct and official.

Logically (e.g. on maps) it's treated as a path running parallel to the road, in contrast to a pavement/sidewalk which is a part of the road.

Comment: Thank you @chris-h for the info! I probably like to call it footpath, as it's not possible for bikes to come here (due to staircase at the entry).

Comment: Footpath would not be used in American English, FYI.

Answer (score 7):

This image shows a similar structure from the Humber Bridge in the UK. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humber_Bridge#Image_gallery) from where it came refers to this as a **Walkway**.

[image: umber Bridge walkway]

> Picture credit: By J Rowson (Own work) [CC BY-SA 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), via Wikimedia Commons

Comment: *Walkway* is the word I would use in Canadian English.

Answer (score 3):

If the area people can walk on is essentially the same height as or the same road surface as the area to the right of the guardrail, it's a footpath. If it is higher such that there is a curb or drop, it's a sidewalk. It may also be called a pedestrian access area.

Comment: Sidewalk is an American English term. The British English equivalent is "pavement" (Paving slabs are commonly used alongside normal urban roads in the UK).

Answer (score 0):

> **Traverse**
> [trav-ers, truh-vurs]
> /noun
>
> 19. a place where one may traverse or cross; crossing.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/traverse)